# How to set the charset when using docbkx to generate HTML output?

Tags: docbook

How to set the charset when using docbkx to generate html output?
The default is

```xml
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

I want to change it to

```xml
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Are you talking about `docbkx:generate-html` phase?

Comment: are the quotes correct for content and charset? It looks like you might be missing some `"`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding the xsl:output element to your stylesheet:

```xml
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
```

So the XSL stylesheet will look like this one

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                version="1.0"> 
  <xsl:import href="${docbookroot}/html/docbook.xsl"/> 
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```